# Tool to determine MP3 actual quality

Tags: linux, command-line, python, mp3

I am looking for a CLI tool that will give me an output of the frequency range of an MP3 file, like Spek does, but without the image file. I need to this to analyse a large library of MP3 files to determine which files are not "true" 320Kbps.

Comment: Could you clarify why you want to analyse the frequency range to eliminate files which don’t have a certain bitrate? The two aren’t directly related AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

Probably `ffprobe` is what you need. It comes with the package `ffmpeg` (in debian and derivative), also you can download and compile with extra features from [here](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html).

Just pass the file as an argument like

```
ffprobe miFile.mp3
```

and you will get the information of the file.

For more information you can check the man page of `ffprobe` and if your are interested, the man of the `ffmpeg` too. Both are very powerfull progrmas and can do a lot

Check this [link](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips) for examples of `ffprobe`

Comment: This is not what OP wants. You can take any low-quality mp3 and re-encode it in 320kbps.